# Heap Corruption or Stack corruption

Tags: c++, memory-management, crash

My application crashes due to some problems. THe call stack is available for the crash. How can I know that the whether the crash is due to heap corruption or stack corruption by looking at the call stack?

Comment: You probably can't - you'll need to look at more than just a backtrace to figure out what's gone wrong.  Why does it crash?  Did you dereference a bad pointer?  Did it jump off into the weeds?

Comment: And does it always crash in the same place?

Comment: You dint looked into the code and debug, did you??

Answer (score 1):

You can use valgrind for checking for memory leaks in your program.

Or, better still, use ddd/gdb to step through and see. Either ways, it is difficult to know without taking a look at the valgrind output.

Usually, if the problem is with a pointer, it would be because of heap corruption.

HTH,
Sriram

Comment: Unfortunately, valgrind isn't always an option.  For example, it's not available in Sparc/Solaris environments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you posted the almost same question twice, probably shouldn't do that.  Since you are working in windows environment (I gathered that from your other post), when your program crashes, get a dump file (use VS or adplus to create one).  Once you have the file, load it up in windbg.  Run "!analyze -v".  If you have a heap corruption, that will be indicated as part of the analysis report.

I've seen way too many times when a developer would stare at a crash that looks weird and just declare, "since I don't know what it is must be a heap corruption".  4/5 times when I helped them (at least that's my experience) it was a simple application logic error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in debug in Windows by placing the following line at the start of main (if using Win32):

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF|_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF|_CRTDBG_CHECK_CRT_DF|
         _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF |_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF);
```

This will break when there's an issue. However, I've found Microsoft's Application Verifier easy to use and very useful. At times it's taken me right to the offending line causing the corruption. You need to download Application verifier from Microsoft:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028
```

Then install and look for the exe in your Windows\System32 folder call appverif.exe.
Point it to your executable and then run your application in debug as you would usually do in Visual Studio. Visual Studio will break where the issue is detected (the real cause might be elsewhere but if you know what your code is done you should know what's going on).